# Como fazer upload de imagens com id diferentes

Tags: php, sql

Quero saber como posso fazer upload de imagens com id diferentes ou seja, tenho um sistema de upload funcional só que esse sistema é um id somente, quero saber como faço para cada imagem enviada o id mude ou seja, tenho um sistema de e-commerce e quando o usuário for inserir suas informações ele vai fazer o upload de uma imagem para o seu perfil. Só que esse meu script não estou conseguindo fazer, alguma ajuda?
Olha o arquivo de upload:

**Inserir_inf_user.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
</body>
<?php
    //Include da conexão
    include_once("conexao.php");

    //Definição de variáveis
    $nome=$_POST ["nome"];
    $email=$_POST ["email"];
    $data_nascimento=$_POST ["data_nascimento"];
    $cpf=$_POST ["cpf"];
    $arquivo=$_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
    $cep=$_POST ["cep"];
    $bairro=$_POST ["bairro"];
    $cidade=$_POST ["cidade"];
    $estado=$_POST ["estado"];
    $endereco=$_POST ["endereco"];
    $idusuario=$_POST ["idusuario"];

    //Pasta onde o arquivo vai ser salvo
    $_UP['pasta'] = '../Fotos_perfis/';

    //Tamanho máximo do arquivo em Bytes
    $_UP['tamanho'] = 1024*1024*100; //5mb

    //Array com a extensões permitidas
    $_UP['extensoes'] = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif');

    //Renomeiar
    $_UP['renomeia'] = false;

    //Array com os tipos de erros de upload do PHP
    $_UP['erros'][0] = 'Não houve erro';
    $_UP['erros'][1] = 'O arquivo no upload é maior que o limite do PHP';
    $_UP['erros'][2] = 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho especificado no HTML';
    $_UP['erros'][3] = 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente';
    $_UP['erros'][4] = 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo';

    //Verifica se houve algum erro com o upload. Sem sim, exibe a mensagem do erro
    if($_FILES['arquivo']['error'] != 0){
        die("Não foi possivel fazer o upload, erro: <br />". $_UP['erros'][$_FILES['arquivo']['error']]);
        exit; //Para a execução do script
    }

    //Faz a verificação da extensao do arquivo
    $extensao = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['arquivo']['name'])));
    if(array_search($extensao, $_UP['extensoes'])=== false){        
        echo "
            <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=http://localhost/projetos/Kingscripts/PT-BR/Informacoes_usuarioPT-BR.php?id=$idusuario'>
            <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                alert(\"O produto não foi inserido, extesão inválida.\");
            </script>
        ";
    }

    //Faz a verificação do tamanho do arquivo
    else if ($_UP['tamanho'] < $_FILES['arquivo']['size']){
        echo "
            <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=http://localhost/projetos/Kingscripts/PT-BR/Informacoes_usuarioPT-BR.php?id=$idusuario'>
            <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                alert(\"Arquivo muito grande.\");
            </script>
        ";
    }

    //O arquivo passou em todas as verificações, hora de tentar move-lo para a pasta foto
    else{
        //Primeiro verifica se deve trocar o nome do arquivo
        if($_UP['renomeia'] == true){
            //Cria um nome baseado no UNIX TIMESTAMP atual e com extensão .jpg
            $nome_final = time().'.jpg';
        }else{
            //mantem o nome original do arquivo
            $nome_final = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
        }
        //Verificar se é possivel mover o arquivo para a pasta escolhida
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $_UP['pasta']. $nome_final)){
            //Upload efetuado com sucesso, exibe a mensagem
            $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO usuario_informacao (nome, email, data_nascimento, cpf, nome_imagem, cep, bairro, cidade, estado, endereco) VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$data_nascimento', '$cpf', '$nome_final', '$cep', '$bairro', '$cidade', '$estado', '$endereco', WHERE idusuario = '$idusuario')");
            echo "
                <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=http://localhost/projetos/Kingscripts/PT-BR/Informacoes_usuarioPT-BR.php?id=$idusuario'>
                <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"Produto inserido com Sucesso.\");
                </script>
            ";  
        }else{
            //Upload não efetuado com sucesso, exibe a mensagem
            echo "
                <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=http://localhost/projetos/Kingscripts/PT-BR/Informacoes_usuarioPT-BR.php?id=$idusuario'>
                <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"Produto não foi inserido com Sucesso.\");
                </script>
            ";
        }
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Explica isso aí melhor pq não deu pra entender não. Seu texto está muito confuso e meio sem sentido.

Comment: Explica melhor qual sua dúvida, não entendi muito bem